# Conditionally add custom coloring to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, java, json, leaflet

I'm setting custom properties for each element in java to a `JSONArray` which is then added to the `JSONObject`.

But now, on some condition I have to add custom *"properties"* to display a marker in a different color.

What is the best approach to conditionally color a `leaflet marker`.

### Notice

This is basically a design question. Should I filter/modify/indicate it already in the backend,
where I build my JSONObject or should I iterate over the built Object in JavaScript and find the *oldest* Date there and give it custom coloring?

### Example

```
properties.put("popupContent", //
            bold("gps_popup_fztz_label").append(fZ).append(" / ").append(tZ).append(BR)//
                    .append(bold("gps_popup_code_label")).append(code).append(BR)//
                    .append(bold("gps_popup_text_label")).append(text).append(BR)//
                    .append(bold("gps_popup_status_label")).append(status).append(BR)//
                    .append(bold("gps_popup_zeit_label").append(ereignisZeit).toString()));
```

If `ereignisZeit` is highest, then marker is red, if lowest, green else blue.

### Extra

I thought about sorting the List, and the first item is red and last one green, rest blue. But maybe there is a better, without need to modify existing JSON to give it custom coloring.

Comment: Really depends on your architecture. I would assume that whatever your data layer is, you can more easily get your results sorted by date(`ORDER BY timestamp ASC` or whatever) there. So if your API between your backend and frontend guarantees that order, you can just specially handle the first(`[0]`) element of your data to add the colour.

Comment: @KarlReid yes, this is the case. So you telling me to take the first element (frontend) and give it the custom coloring

Comment: Yeah, that is how I would do it. As long as you are confident that the order of the data you get from the backend is well-defined, and you just want to make a UI change in the display of the data, you can just take the first element and colour it.

Comment: What are those `bold()` calls? Which object it creates has an `append` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give me a good reason to do it in front, after you already made your JSON in the backend? Just make it like you need it in the 1st place, where you are making it instead reworking it later.

Unless you are talking about colors in a sense of designing the UI? Then it should be done on frontend if not for anything else then to keep the separation of concerns and keep the styling where it should be.

You might wanna change styling later, you don't wanna rebuild your JSON data because of that.

From the question, it's hard to tell what exactly do the colors symbolize. If it's data - backend, if it's UI design - frontend.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response: it’s just for the frontend, I don’t need the Data it’s just used to give the leaflet Marker custom coloring

Comment: @0x45, well, look at how is that marker different and then send that data (I'm assuming some kind of state property) to UI. On UI, apply the coloring based on the data property via css or something.

Comment: Okay, so @M.Prokhorov you are telling me to set the state at backend, read that property on frontend, and do that styling accordingly?

Comment: @0x45, Precisely. For example, sets make that marker have a property `gps_level`, which according to your description will have three values: `{HIGH | NORMAL | LOW}`. Then your frontend reads `gps_level` and sets the color, or different icon, or whatever else, and your backend shouldn't need to care about what the frontend did.

Comment: I agree with @M.Prokhorov

Comment: Okay, I liked your idea of doing it "in the first place".

I've added a custom property when first/last element and now I'm reading this property on frontend to set styling.